Problema al ejecutar un .py en la terminal en Pycharm
espero que se encuentren bien, tengo un problema al querer ejecutar un .py en Pycharm, escribo el .py en la terminal y cuando doy enter no me aparece nada.
Para aclarar, no se si es necesario pero por las dudas lo digo, tengo Python 3.9 y Pycharm 2024.1
Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.
Saludos

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Para ejecutar los .py puedes realizar ejecutando en el terminal python test.py (test.py, es el nombre de tu archivo que contiene el código) o desde el botón  de play de Pycharm.
Nota: Asegúrate de que tu código imprima algún resultado caso contrario no se mostrara nada en el terminal o en la Python console
Demostración:


Buenas tardes, gracias por tu respuesta, cuando realizo lo que me indicaste me sucede esto:   No se encontr¾ Python; ejecuta sin argumentos para instalar desde Microsoft Store o deshabilita este acceso directo en Configuraci¾n > Administrar alias de ejecuci¾n de la aplicaci¾n.

tienes instalado python en tu computador? Según  el mensaje mencionas es por que no tienes instalado o configura las variables de entorno de python, en caso de no tener instalado responde a este comentario para editar la respuesta y poder agregar los pasos que debes hacer

Sisi, lo tengo instalado
